# scikit-learn GridSearchCV doesn't work as samples increase

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, enthought, anaconda

The following script runs fine on my machine with `n_samples=1000`, but dies (no error, just stops working) with `n_samples=10000`.  This only happens using the Anaconda python distribution (numpy 1.8.1) but is fine with Enthought's (numpy 1.9.2).  Any ideas what would be causing this?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import log_loss_scorer
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np

X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=50,
                                       n_informative=35, n_redundant=10,
                                       random_state=1984)

lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=1984)
param_grid = {'C': np.logspace(-1, 2, 4, base=2)}
kf = KFold(n=y.size, n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1984)
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=lr, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=log_loss_scorer, cv=kf, verbose=100,
                  n_jobs=-1)

gs.fit(X, y)
```

Note: I'm using sklearn 0.16.1 in both distributions and am using OS X.

I've noticed that upgrading to numpy version 1.9.2 with Enthought distribution (by updating manually) breaks the grid search.  I haven't had any luck downgrading Anaconda numpy version to 1.8.1 though.

Comment: versions of numpy and sklearn in each distribution?

Comment: run with `python -v` to find more information on the failure.

Comment: It doesn't actually fail, just stops actually making any progress on the grid search and "hangs" (I see no CPU in Activity Monitor).  The versions are: Enthought: numpy 1.8.1, sklearn 0.16.1; Anaconda: bumpy 1.9.2, sklearn 0.16.1

Comment: With n_jobs=1 it does work, right?

Comment: @user1507844 Can you be a bit more explicit about what you mean by updating numpy manually in canopy ? I tried your script with 100x more samples, and it does not hang for me. Could you give the out output of `egginst -l` in the terminal you are running this script, as well as the exact command you use to launch this script ?

Comment: I was mistaken.  It actually never hangs in Canopy.  As far as I understand the difference is the linear algebra library against which the Anaconda and Enthought distributions are built.  The Anaconda lin alg library tries to be multithreaded which doesn't play well with multiprocessing sitting on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows? If so, you need to protect the code with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

Otherwise multiprocessing will not work.

Comment: Ah. Then it is probably because you built numpy yourself and linked against accelerate? That doesn't play well with multiprocessing. If you avoid building numpy yourself you should be fine.

Comment: No, just using the standard Anaconda distribution and didn't pay for the accelerate upgrade.  Do they build against accelerate even if I don't use it?

Comment: Shouldn't. That is odd. Maybe open an issue in the issue tracker.

Comment: Andreas is referring to the OS X Accelerate Framework, which Anaconda is indeed built against (not to be confused with the Continuum Analytics Accelerate product, which gives numpy that is linked against mkl).

Answer (score 0):

Per Andreas's comment, the problem seems to be with multi threading in the linear algebra library.  I solved it with the following command in the terminal:

`export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=1`

My (weak) understanding is that this limits the linear algebra's library use of multiple threads and lets multiprocessing handle multithreading as it wants.